# Por que a conversão binária do SQL Server não retorna um valor binário?

Tags: sql, varbinary, binary

Por que quando utilizo o seguinte comando em SQL Server 2005

```
select convert(varbinary(16),N'123')
```

retorna `0x310032003300` e não `1111011` que seria o valor binário?

Answer (score 6):

@dellasavia, `1111011` é apenas 1 byte, no caso um N'123' é um nvarchar com 3 caracteres.

Sendo que cada caracter de um nvarchar ocupa 2 bytes, totalizando 6 bytes.

`0x310032003300` pode ser lido da seguinte forma em HEX:

HEX: `31` `00` `32` `00` `33` `00`

O Binario neste caso seria algo como:

Binary: `00110001` `00000000` `00110010` `00000000` `00110011` `00000000`

porem se ao inves de utilizamos um nvarchar, fizemos a conversão de um tinyint, então você iria conseguir o resultado esperado.

```
DECLARE @valor as tinyint
SET @valor = 123
SELECT convert(binary(1), @valor)
```

Mas neste caso, você iria ver um output `0x7B` (HEX), que é o mesmo de `01111011` (Binary).